# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Эти системы успешно эксплуатируются на многих (,) давно построенных и модернизированных в последние годы предприятиях.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Эти системы успешно эксплуатируются на
> многих (,) давно построенных и
> модернизированных в последние годы
> предприятиях.

Я бы убрал союз "и":

*Эти системы успешно эксплуатируются на многих давно построенных, модернизированных в последние годы предприятиях.*

Comment: Делаю вывод, что запятая не нужна. Спасибо. :)